# jQuery DataTables Search on mouseclick

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working on jQuery Datatables. I have implemented predictive search functionality for the Search textbox such that as the user begins typing, it displays a list of 10 most recent items/strings that were searched. Now the issue here is that if I select any of the list items using keyboard the filtering takes place instantly i.e. on every keypress whereas when I select a list item with a mouse-click it doesnt filter the table. I have to hit enter in order to filter the table. I want to be able to filter the table on keypress as well as mouseclick. How can this be implemented in datatables? Any suggestions would be of great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this;

First you need to setup a JQuery event on the click, so give all the options in the drop down list a class of say recentItems.  Then you can write something like this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.recentItems').click(function(){
           var filterString = $('.dataTables_filter :input').val();
           oTable.fnFilter(filterString);
   });

});
```

This assumes you gave your datatable a variable name of oTable.

Comment: use multiple events .. `keypress` and `click` :)

Comment: @Garbage, datatables already preforms the filter on keyup.  This is a problem of a custom input not triggering the filter.

Comment: yes it is custom input ,then how it going to recognize the `keyup` event ? if we are using custom input then we should bind multiple events [if we really need it] :)

Comment: The input field is not custom, that is a built in part of data tables plugin. The drop down suggestions he is prompting with is custom. When the user clicks one it fills in the standard input box but it does not trigger the filter.

Comment: NP, please mark as the correct answer if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#filter-data-button').click(function(){
    oTable.search('your value').draw();
});
```